# In Ubuntu, xdg-open command is not working

Tags: 14.04, xdg-open

I'm new with Ubuntu, and I read in another thread that to open a file in the default editor (gedit for me), I need to run `xdg-open`, but for some reason, when I run the command `xdg-open app.js` I'm getting a `bash: xdg-open: command not found` notification. Why is it?

Following a request from a comment, the output of `echo $PATH` is :

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/efiminzer/.local/bin:/home/efiminzer/bin
```

Comment: When you run 'xdg-open' does it throw the error?

Comment: Yes, right after I run the command

Comment: What's the exact error message?  Copy/paste it into your question as an edit

Comment: I've edited the exact error notification I've got

Comment: Please add also the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `whoami; groups; stat /usr/bin/xdg-open; apt-cache policy xdg-utils; dpkg -L xdg-utils | grep bin`

Answer (score 20):

Install/reinstall the package `xdg-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-utils
```

`/usr/bin/xdg-open` is part of this package.

Comment: I've installed reinstalled the package and still the same error message